# import data too many text file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, variables, dataset, text-files, nlp-question-answering

i want import too many text file in matlab. 129013 files!
i used the following code:

```
    for i=1:129013
k=importdata('filename.txt')
eval(['A', num2str(i) , ' = ' ,k) ,';']);
end
whos
```

Of course, do not accept variable number 129,013.

The problem is the code? And how high number of variables defined?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: this is an extreme horrible process of looping through each file, why don't you combine all the txt files into 1 file using cmd/bash before loading that 1 file in?

Comment: For starters, you're just importing the same file over and over again..  And why would you use eval here? Just put it in a cell or append a matrix or whatever is your use case...

Comment: Files are independent and should not be combined.
I used to define the variables of 'eval'.
How do I use????

Comment: @farideh As he suggested, use a cell array. Also what version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: number of data in each files is different.
and data are string. 
matlab2012

Comment: @farideh Right that's why you use a cell array. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you *really insist* on using `eval` (you shouldn't), you are going to have issues because you are trying to concatenate `k` (your data) with a string.

```
['A', num2str(i) , ' = ' ,k) ,';']
```

You instead want to concatenate the *string* `k` to refer to the `k` you loaded.

```
eval(['A', num2str(i), '= k;']);
```

Also, maybe your real code is different but it appears that you're loading the *same file* (`filename.txt`) over and over.

That being said, creating thousands of variables in your workspace with `eval` like this is a very poor approach and anything you want to do with those variables is going to require even more usage of `eval`. **Additionally, in versions of MATLAB older than R2015b, you can't even create as many variables as you're trying to create as MATLAB is limited to `2^16` variables**.

You'd be much better off using a cell array to store your data.

```
for k = 1:129013
    A{k} = importdata(sprintf('filename%d.txt', k));
end
```

Comment: NOT RUN:: Warning: Escape sequence 'u' is not valid. See 'help sprintf' for valid escape
sequences. 
Error using importdata (line 216)
Unable to load file.
Use TEXTSCAN or FREAD for more complex formats.


Caused by:
    Error using fread
    Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved as follows:

```
for k = 1:129013
fid=sprintf('%d.txt', k);
    A{k} = importdata(['filename',fid]);
end
```